# why bootstrap cols overlap the fixed header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a fix header and I have used a col class of bootstrap so when I scroll down the col box overlaps the fixed header.
--Header CSS--

```
#heading{
            position: fixed;
            background: #f16f00;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-size: 100%;
            border: 1px solid;
            font-size:80px;
        }
```

--Wrapper--

```
#wrapper{
margin-top:100px;
}
```

--Html--

```
    <div class="container" id='heading'>
    Heading Area
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div id='wrapper'>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues">', '</a>') ?></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
```

This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjjuuwa4/22/)

suggestions are required 
Thank you

Comment: Need to set a higher z-index on `#heading`. Have you checked the source for http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/?

Comment: sry but i am not getting z-index on a whole page . what to do with that?

Comment: If you actually look at what, say, the `.navbar-fixed-top` class does, you'd see a `z-index: 1030;` rule; since the rest of the page has a (much) lower z-index, the content will scroll under the navbar. I assume that's the effect you're after?

Comment: thank you navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top it helps to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following will help you:

**CSS:**

```
    #heading{
                position: fixed;
                background: #f16f00;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                background-size: 100%;
                border: 1px solid;
                font-size:80px;
                top:0;
            }

#wrapper{
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues">', '</a>') ?></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues">', '</a>') ?></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container" id='fix'> 
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues">', '</a>') ?></p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container"> 
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
<div class="container"> 
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
</div>
</div>
<div class="container" id='heading'>
    Heading Area
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bjjuuwa4/30/)

Comment: what is the reason behind this?

Comment: It is because Header div you defined first then other so, default it's z-index is low. And you make header `position:fixed`  but didn't give `top:0;`